# Unable to read from Guest OS in VirtualBox. Host: Windows 8, Guest: CentOS 6

Tags: oracle, configuration, centos, virtualhost, centos6

I'm hoping to have a situation where I can write code in the CentOS guest, and have it presented to me in a browser under the host OS.  I'm currently using Windows 8 as my host.

[image]
My current network settings, and...

[image]
When typing ifconfig into the guest.

All I want to is to be able to get PHP code that is in /var/www/html on the guest machine, and have it show in the host machine's browsers.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give a look at [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), a tool that allows you to replicate development environments on a guest machine and run the applications on your host's browser by opening a port that gives you access to localhost of the guest machine.

You can even edit the code in your host vm, but all the dependencies of the project are hosted by the guest vm.